# open the container having buttons with button click in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I have a form which contains image buttons located on WEST side of Form. I want to open the particular container having few more buttons by clicking one of the button.

As in image there are three buttons. When I click first button it should open the colored button container infront of them. When I click button 2 it should open the container.

Its works fine when I close first container and then open second container.
But when I click first button it opens container at exact position, but the container of second button appears at bottom, whereas it need to open infront of the button 2. 
If I click second button first, the container appears at top and container of first button appears at bottom

May be its bit confusing. But I think got the clear idea, I just wnt to open the container when button is clicked infront of the clicked button, but they are misaligning with each other.

So. May I know how to place these conatiners so that they open exactly at the position of the particular button clicked?

```
class Pallet extends Container {
    ColorIcon redIcon;
    ColorIcon blueIcon;
    ColorIcon greenIcon;


    Container panel;

    public Pallet() {

        super();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(Component.RIGHT));
        getStyle().setMargin(115, 10, 10, 10);
        panel = new Container();
        panel.getStyle().setBgColor(0x323232);
        panel.getStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS)); 
        panel.getStyle().setBorder(Border.createLineBorder(2, 0xffffff));
        panel.getStyle().setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        panel.getStyle().setMargin(30, 10, 10, 10);
        panel.setSelectedStyle(panel.getStyle());
        Container row1 = new Container();
        row1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        redIcon = new ColorIcon(0xff0000, this);
        row1.addComponent(redIcon);

        greenIcon = new ColorIcon(0x00ff00, this);
        row1.addComponent(greenIcon);

        blueIcon = new ColorIcon(0x0000ff, this);
        row1.addComponent(blueIcon);

        panel.addComponent(row1);
        addComponent(panel);

        }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: How you show the container would have helped. I would have used a popup dialog or popup interaction dialog.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Hi Shai, I have added the code I used for this.

Comment: What's `setStartXPos` isn't that what you're asking about? You also set the layered pane to flow layout, I don't understand why.